# NIntegrate giving contradictory and inaccurate results

Tags: numerical-integration

I was computing following surface integral:

```
NIntegrate[Exp[-(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)/4]/(4 Pi), {x, y, z} \[Element]  
ImplicitRegion[k * z + (x^2 - z^2 + x^2 y + z^2 y - y + y^3) == 0, 
{{x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}, {z, -100, 100}}], WorkingPrecision -> 8]
```

in which I tried different values of k. Namely:

1. When I try **k = 0, 0.1, 0.2, ... , 0.9, 1**, I get the outputs 1.5189666, 1.12735, 1.72466, 1.72553, 1.20739, 1.4885114, 1.73858, 1.7463, 1.22273, 1.4347761, 1.3981121 respectively.
2. However, when I try **k = 0, 1/10, 2/10, ... , 9/10, 10/10**, I get instead the outputs 1.5189666, 1.4702818, 1.4065715, 1.4207811, 1.4319435, 1.4885114,
   1.4736194, 1.4468079, 1.4246652, 1.4347761, 1.3981121 respectively.

The difference between this two sets of outputs is completely absurd, since I was essentially just using the same set of values for k! In fact, in both cases, the results do not seem satisfactory, since the results  oscillate as k increases, which sounds unlikely.

So what could I do to increase the accuracy? Thank you.

Edit:

I tried Ulrich Neumann's code. The problem is still here.

[image]

Comment: I get the same integrals for k = 0.1 & 1/10 and for 0.2 & 2/10 (V12.2). I can't reproduce your problem. -- That said, I would guess that the approximation of the surface is the source of inconsistency.  That's done with a mesh, and then `NIntegrate` approximates the integral over the approximate surface. You might be better off coding the surface integral yourself.

Comment: "...I was essentially just using the same set of values for k! ". No, you were not. The first a machine precision, the second are exact. This can cause (and usually will cause) differing behaviors in numerical integration.

A review of the sections "The Uncertainties of Numerical Mathematics" and "NIntegrate" might be in order.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for the help. What values did you get? Moreover, since I am completely inexperienced in numerical integration: may I ask what method do you suggest to code the surface integral? (I tried parametrizing the surface by x and z, but that would make the integrand very complicated)

Comment: I got the same you got for 0.1, 0.2.  I do surface integrals using the formulas I learned in multivariable calculus. They translate into iterated integrals, which you can plug directly into `NIntegrate`. I haven't tried it on yours, but it looks like the equations the region can be solved.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I tried doing that, by expressing y in terms of x and z. But then integrand becomes very complicated, and we have "NIntegrate failed to converge" type problem.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish using such small working precision.

Comment: @AntonAntonov In this case (using regions/FEM), `NIntegrate` switches to machine precision and ignores `WorkingPrecision` (I think).  My first thought was the same as yours, but after realizing what was going on, it seemed of minor importance in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you control the construction of surface mesh, you can control the convergence of the integral.

I ran each `Block` with the `MaxCellMeasure` parameter `a = 1` and then `a = 0.1`.  One could continue with `a` approaching zero. But since the last block took 20K seconds, I decided an error estimate of $2\times10^{-5}$ was good enough.  It would be nice to do one more step to confirm the convergence rate, but not on my computer, which I need to use for my own work.

For `k = 0.5`, I got an integral of `1.5071772672526136`, with an error approximately less than `0.0000206405`.

Since the decays rapidly away from the origin, I subdivided the surface to approximate it better near the origin.

```
Block[{k = 5/10, a = 0.1, r = 6},
  meshes =
   Join[
    DiscretizeRegion[#,
       MaxCellMeasure -> {"Area" -> 5 a}
       ] & /@
     {ImplicitRegion[
       k*z + (x^2 - z^2 + x^2 y + z^2 y - y + y^3) == 
        0, {{x, r, 100}, {y, -100, 100}, {z, -100, 100}}],
      ImplicitRegion[
       k*z + (x^2 - z^2 + x^2 y + z^2 y - y + y^3) == 
        0, {{x, -100, -r}, {y, -100, 100}, {z, -100, 100}}],
      ImplicitRegion[
       k*z + (x^2 - z^2 + x^2 y + z^2 y - y + y^3) == 
        0, {{x, -r, r}, {y, -100, 100}, {z, r, 100}}],
      ImplicitRegion[
       k*z + (x^2 - z^2 + x^2 y + z^2 y - y + y^3) == 
        0, {{x, -r, r}, {y, -100, 100}, {z, -100, -r}}]},
    {DiscretizeRegion[
      ImplicitRegion[
       k*z + (x^2 - z^2 + x^2 y + z^2 y - y + y^3) == 
        0, {{x, -r, r}, {y, -r, r}, {z, -r, r}}],
      MaxCellMeasure -> {"Area" -> a/100}
      ]}
    ];
  last = current;
  current = 
   NIntegrate[
      Exp[-(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)/4]/(4 Pi), {x, y, z} \[Element] #] & /@ 
    meshes;
  Total[current]
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
current - last

(*
{138.988, 1.5072}  {time, total integral}
{-5.89258*10^-8, -5.58132*10^-8, -2.29937*10^-8, -2.69889*10^-8,
 -0.000199036}     {error estimates
*)
```

Refine the neighborhood of the origin further:

```
current0 = Last@current;
Block[{k = 5/10, a = 0.1, r = 6},
  meshes0 =
   {DiscretizeRegion[
     ImplicitRegion[
      k*z + (x^2 - z^2 + x^2 y + z^2 y - y + y^3) == 
       0, {{x, -r, r}, {y, -r, r}, {z, -r, r}}],
     MaxCellMeasure -> {"Area" -> a/1000}
     ]};
  last0 = current0;
  current0 = 
   NIntegrate[
      Exp[-(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)/4]/(4 Pi), {x, y, z} \[Element] #] & /@ 
    meshes0;
  Total[current0]
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
current0 - last0
(*
{20692., 1.50714}  {time, integral}
{-0.0000204757}    {error estimate}
*)

Total@current[[;; 4]] + First@current0

(*  1.5071772672526136`   *)
```

Here's the neighborhood of the origin:

```
ByteCount@meshes0
meshes0
(*  917204536  *)
```

[image]

Here is the mesh that `NIntegrate` uses (zoomed in on the origin), which shows a poor approximation of the surface:

```
Block[{k = 5/10},
 Trace[
  NIntegrate[
   Exp[-(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)/4]/(4 Pi), {x, y, z} \[Element] 
    ImplicitRegion[
     k*z + (x^2 - z^2 + x^2 y + z^2 y - y + y^3) == 
      0, {{x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}, {z, -100, 100}}], 
   WorkingPrecision -> 8],
  _DiscretizeRegion,
  TraceInternal -> True]
 ]
(*
{{HoldForm@
DiscretizeRegion[
 ImplicitRegion[
  x^2 - y + x^2 y + y^3 + z/2 - z^2 + y z^2 == 0 && -100 <= x <= 
    100 && -100 <= y <= 100 && -100 <= z <= 100, {x, y, z}], 
 PrecisionGoal -> 4.00854, AccuracyGoal -> \[Infinity]]}}
*)

Show[
 % // ReleaseHold,
 PlotRange -> {{-100, 100}, {-100, 100}, {-100, 100}}/20
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I figured out to use DiscretizeRegion too. With MaxCellMeasure=0.1, I get the integral equals 1.52155, which should be right because I think you missed the region (x,y,z) in [r,r] x ([-100,r] ⋃ [r,100]) x [-r,r]. But there's a bit in your code I don't understand, why does "current - last" give an error estimate?

Comment: @AdCh Oops, sorry if I missed a region.  As for error estimates, suppose you have a sequence of computations $a_1, a_2,\dots$ that are supposed to converge to a limit $L$. If they are converging "rapidly" in the sense that $a_{k}$ is closer to $L$ than it is to $a_{k-1}$, then the error $| L-a_k|$ is less than $| a_k - a_{k-1}|$, that is, less than the current $a_k$ minus the last $a_{k-1}$. I was dividing the max area by 10 at each step, but I did not actually verify that the process was converging "rapidly" due to time. I performed the steps manually because of the time they took.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Clever solution (as so often)!. How did you calculate the error estimates(given as comments)?

Comment: @MichaelE2 ...so far I tried  `int = Reap[
  NIntegrate[
   Exp[-(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)/4]/(4 Pi), {x, y, z} \[Element]  
    DiscretizeRegion@ 
     ImplicitRegion[
      k*z + (x^2 - z^2 + x^2 y + z^2 y - y + y^3) == 
       0, {{x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}, {z, -100, 100}}], 
   IntegrationMonitor :> (Sow[Total@Through[#["Error"]]] &) ]]` but `IntegrationMonitor` doesn't work???

Comment: @UlrichNeumann "I ran each Block with the MaxCellMeasure parameter a = 1 and then a = 0.1" (in that order). After the second run `last` will be equal to the integrals for `a = 1` and `current` will be equal to the integrals for `a = 0.1`. In fact, I tested it on a few sequences such as `a = 10, 1, 0.1`, for which the successive error bounds were $2\times10^{-4}$, $2\times10^{-5}$ respectively, IIRC. I ran it on a smaller `a` and it caused my whole computer to crash (ran out of memory, I suppose, since the kernel was using tens of GB more than my RAM).

Comment: If you're asking how I computed $|a_k-L|$, I didn't. I computed $|a_k-a_{k-1}|$, which bounds $|a_k-L|$ if $a_k$ is rapidly convergent.  I inferred rapid convergence from the test runs. When my computer crashed, I lost that data. I was unable to include it without going through the long testing again, which I don't have time to do.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann `IntegrationMonitor` does not work on all methods.  It works on most or all of the `"GlobalAdaptive"` and `"LocalAdaptive"` methods, I think. The `MeshRegion` based method is one it does not work on. The `MeshRegion` approach is not really capable of high precision, at least in this case (within practical computer limitations).

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for your  helpful answers! I played around with `IntegrationMonitor` found in one of  your   stackexchange answers and wondering why it doesn't work with `MeshRegion`.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show the code, how you calculated results for different `k`!

With the definition

```
int[k_?NumericQ] := 
NIntegrate[Exp[-(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)/4]/(4 Pi), {x, y, z} \[Element] 
ImplicitRegion[k*z + (x^2 - z^2 + x^2 y + z^2 y - y + y^3) ==0, {{x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}, {z, -100, 100}}],WorkingPrecision -> 8]
```

Mathematica evaluates the same integral for decimal  and rational values `k`:

```
{int[#], int[Rationalize[#]]} &[.1]
(*{1.12735, 1.12735}*)

{int[#], int[Rationalize[#]]} &[.5]
(*{1.13474, 1.13474}*)

{int[#], int[Rationalize[#]]} &[1.]
(*{1.3981104, 1.3981104}*)
```

The considered surface varies a little bit with `k`

```
Manipulate[
ContourPlot3D[Evaluate[k*z + (x^2 - z^2 + x^2 y + z^2 y - y + y^3) ==0], {x, -100, 100 }, {y, -5/2 , 5/2 }, {z, -100, 100}  ,AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, Mesh -> None], 
{{k, .1}, 0., 1., .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank. I just run your code in my mathematica, and the 3 sets of output I got back are the same as those in my post. Note that for k=0.5 (and 5/10), my output (1.4885114) is different than yours (1.13474). So the conclusion is my mathematica is problematic. (I'm using 12.2 student version)

Comment: How did you evaluate the integrals? If you substitute "by hand" into the NIntegrate expression it might be possible that Mathematica  performs different symbolic processing actions

Comment: I just directly copy-and-pasted you code. I have just attached a picture in my question showing that.